# Using Tkinter as a notification Then returning to function of program

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am using `Tkinter` as a notification of an upcoming mouse event and I want the program to continue with its main function but it keeps closing after notification appears. What do i need to add to the follow code to get it to return to the function that called it?

```
def sendMessage():#THIS IS MY NOTIFICATION FUNCTION
    popupRoot = Tk()
    popupRoot.lift()
    popupRoot.attributes('-topmost',True)
    popupRoot.after_idle(popupRoot.attributes,'-topmost',False)
    popupRoot.after(10000, exit)
    popupButton = Button(popupRoot, text = "You have 1 minute until mouse events",
                     font = ("Verdana", 12), bg = "yellow", command = exit)
    popupButton.pack()
    popupRoot.geometry('400x50+700+500')
    popupRoot.mainloop()

def wait(howLong, runTime, howRuns, day, x):  #THIS IS THE FUNCTION THAT CALLED THE NOTIFICATION FUNCTION          
    while x < howLong:    
        print "rerun in ", howLong - x, " minute(s)"
        messTime = 1
        if messTime == 1:
            sendMessage()
        time.sleep(60)#1 minute delay to allow carts to return
        x = x + 1

    if x == howLong:
        runTime = runTime + 1
        print "Run time = ", runTime
        print "rerunning program now"
    if runTime == howRuns:
        exitProgram()
    else:
        main(howLong, runTime, howRuns, day)
```

Comment: it ends because in `after()` and in `command=` you use `exit`  which is used to close script. You need `command=popupRoot.destroy` and `after(10000, popupRoot.destroy)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ends because in `after()` and in `command=` you use `exit` which normally is used to close script.

You need `popupRoot.destroy` instead of `exit` in `after(10000, popupRoot.destroy)` and `command=popupRoot.destroy`

Comment: that worked like a charm! thank you.. am still very much learning the 'os' commands and couldn't find it on google. THANK YOU =D